# Dependency and library problems with Ubuntu Server 16.04.2

Tags: mysql, dependencies, ldap

I've just installed Ubuntu Server 16.04.2 LTS, without some installation packages like LAMP and LDAP.

After the installation of the server I tried to install them manually with `apt-get`, but I'm receiving the following error:

```
root@Linux-Services-Server:/usr/local/src# apt-get install slapd ldap-utils 
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
You might want to run 'apt-get -f install' to correct these:
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
libmyodbc : Depends: libmysqlclient18 (>= 5.5.13-1) but it is not installable
slapd : Depends: libslp1 (>= 1.2.1) but it is not going to be installed
E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt-get -f install' with no packages (or specify a solution).
```

If this library  **libmysqlclient18** is so important, why isn't available anymore? I've the following library libmysqlclient20, if this is the new library why doesn't work with `ldap-utils` or `libslp1`, or `mysql`? And many more libraries and programs that needs it.

I also need need this library libmysqlclient18 for others things too, like LDAP with SQL Backend, LDAP installation it self and MySQL installation using `apt-get`.

It is so annoying because I'm using the packages homologated by Ubuntu workgroup and team, and this problem is constant when you need to work with databases.

Comment: How exactly did you install `libmyodbc`? it sounds like you have installed a deprecated package that is not compatible with the mysql packages in the repository

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem, where libslp1 wasn't in the apt cache and it couldn't be installed. I downloaded and installed the .deb package from the web archive and after that I was able to install slapd.

After a little investigation I found that the mirror I was using wasn't up to date (Last update unknown), see: https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+archivemirrors

I changed my mirror (under Software & Updates -> Download from) and it looks fine now.